# How to exclude parent when none of the child record matches a certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a unique set of jobs based on following schema and data:

**Jobs:**

```
JobId       JobTrackNumber      Title       JobPostedDate
1           J11001              Abc         2018-01-01
2           J11002              Pqr         2018-01-01
3           J11003              Lmn         2019-01-01
4           J11004              XYZ         2018-01-01
```

**JobLocationType:**

```
TypeId      LocationNumber      Name        JobId
1           Chicago111          Chicago     1
2           LA222               LA222       1
3           Miami333            Miami333    2
4           Swit444             Swit444     2
5           Peru555             Peru555     3
6           Limu555             Limu555     4
```

**Review:**

```
ReviewId        ReviewLocationType      ReviewDate      
1               Chicago111              2020-01-01
2               Chicago111              2020-02-01
3               LA222                   2020-02-01
4               Miami333                2020-02-01
```

a) Job could have 1 or many JobLocationType.

b) JobLocationType can have 0 or more reviews for a given 'LocationNumber' so `LocationNumber` from `JobLocationType` is being used in `ReviewLocationType` in `Review` table.

For eg: Chicago111 has 2 reviews and LA222 has 1 review in Review table so Job 1 has total 3 reviews.

I am trying to filter unique set of jobs based on following condition:

1. `JobPostedDate` from 2021-01-01 to 2023-01-01
2. Job that has multiple `JobLocationType` and all `JobLocationType` Review is 3 years old from current date based on = `[dbo].[JobLocationType].LocationNumber = [dbo].[Reviews].ReviewLocationType`

   ```
    Or
   ```

   Job that are more than 5 years old.

**Final Output:**

```
JobId       JobTrackNumber  
1           J11001
2           J11002
4           J11004
```

- `J11001` is selected because has 2 `JobLocationType` and both the 2 `JobLocationType` exist in Review table with Review is 3 years old from current date.
- `J11002` is selected because has 2 `JobLocationType` but only 1 `JobLocationType(Miami333)` exist in Review table hence we cannot select that but it does satisfy "`Job that are more 5 years old`" criteria hence selected.
- `J11003` is not selected because it has 1 `JobLocationType` and that does not exist in Review table nor it satisfy "`Job that are more than 5 years old`" criteria.
- `J11004` is selected because it satisfy "`Job that are 5 years old`" criteria although it does not have JobLocationType in Review table.

Output I am getting:

[image]

SQL Fiddle with sample data and query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d8f8/1

**Query:**

```
With ReviewResultCTE(ReviewLocationType,ReviewDate)
as (
    select [ReviewLocationType],[ReviewDate] from Reviews where [ReviewDate] < DATEADD(YEAR,-3,GETDATE())
)

select distinct  job.JobId, job.JobTrackNumber from Jobs job
    inner join [dbo].[JobLocationType] jobLocationType on job.JobId = jobLocationType.JobId
    left join ReviewResultCTE review on review.ReviewLocationType = jobLocationType.LocationNumber
        where not (job.JobExpireDate >='2021-01-01' and job.JobExpireDate < '2023-01-01')
union
select distinct  job.JobId, job.JobTrackNumber from Jobs job
    inner join [dbo].[JobLocationType] jobLocationType on job.JobId = jobLocationType.JobId
        where not (job.JobExpireDate >='2021-01-01' and job.JobExpireDate < '2023-01-01')
        and job.JobExpireDate < DATEADD(YEAR,-5,GETDATE())
```

I will really appreciate any help in fixing the issue.

Comment: @DaleK Its in the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d8f8/1

Comment: And please don't use images for data, use tabular formatted text.

Comment: @DaleK Sure. I will update question to include the query

Comment: All your jobs are over 5 years old, shouldn't you therefore include all of them?

Comment: BTW - you should make sure that the column names you use for your sample data match your fiddle... because its gets very confusion trying to work out which columns is which when they don't match.

Comment: @job id=3 is 6 years old and that is why it is not included and sorry for the confusion

Comment: So is the criteria exactly 5 years old? or less than 5 years old, cos your fiddle (and the way I would read you logic) is saying more than 5 years old `job.JobExpireDate < DATEADD(YEAR,-5,GETDATE())`

Comment: It would help if you abstracted the tables/columns to simpler names to make it clearer what's going on and make the question more useful to future visitors, rather than use the actual names which is convenient for you but less clear for us.

Comment: @DaleK Yes it should be more than 5 years old.

Comment: So as I originally said, all your jobs are more than 5 years old - 6 years is more than 5 :)

Comment: @Bohemian I wanted to present the actual scenario that is why I have used the original names. Sorry if that is causing any confusion

Comment: The partial rename is the most confusing... using `JobPostedDate` in your question and `JobExpireDate` in your fiddle is not helpful.

Comment: @DaleK I have fixed the fiddle and other issue. Now if the  JobPostedDate is '2019-01-01' still Job Id = 3 is coming

Comment: And none of your jobs meet the first criteria `JobPostedDate from 2021-01-01 to 2023-01-01` - meaning its hard to test if you aren't providing the required sample data.

Comment: @DaleK Another issue is if we remove 'LA222' from the Review table which means that  Type Id = 2 does not have a review for Job 'J11001' it is still coming in the result. check this fiddle for this scenario :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4b0f/1

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to address your criteria. Personally I like to calculate the individual logic components and then use regular `AND/OR` logic to filter. I also prefer to start with the core table e.g. `Jobs` and then join on the child table(s).

```
with cte as (
  select j.JobId, j.JobTrackNumber
    , case when j.JobExpireDate >= '2021-01-01' and j.JobExpireDate < '2023-01-01' then 1 else 0 end JobInRange
    , case when JobExpireDate < dateadd(year, -5, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end JobsOlderThanFiveYears
    , sum(case when r.ReviewDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by j.JobId) AllReviews
    , sum(case when r.ReviewDate < dateadd(year, -3, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by j.JobId) AllReviewsOverThreeYears
    , dense_rank() over (partition by j.JobId order by jlt.TypeId asc ) +
      dense_rank() over (partition by j.JobId order by jlt.TypeId desc) - 1 DistinctCountLocations
    , sum(case when r.ReviewId is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by j.JobId) MissingReviews
  from Jobs j
  inner join JobLocationType jlt on jlt.JobId = j.JobId
  left join Reviews r on r.ReviewLocationType = jlt.LocationNumber
)
select JobId, JobTrackNumber
from cte
where JobsOlderThanFiveYears = 1
or (
  JobInRange = 1
  -- Check that # locations is 2+
  and DistinctCountLocations > 1
  -- Check that no locations are missing reviews
  and MissingReviews = 0
  -- Check that all reviews for a job are over 3 years old
  and AllReviews = AllReviewsOverThreeYears
) 
group by JobId, JobTrackNumber;
```

Returns:

| JobId | JobTrackNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | J11001 |
| 2 | J11002 |
| 4 | J11004 |

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vj9QYkic)

Also note how using table aliases makes the query easier to read.

Comment: Appreciate your kind efforts towards helping me but if we remove 'LA222' from the Review table which means that Type Id = 2 does not have a review for Job 'J11001' it is still coming in the result

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow thats because it still meets the criteria as written being `Job that has multiple JobLocationType and all JobLocationType Review is 3 years old` - its still has multiple location types, just one doesn't have a review.

Comment: Yes but all JobLocationType should have a review and if not then that job cannot be included in result set. So it’s all match or none

Comment: You don't say anywhere that all JobLocationType's should have a review... you need to ensure your question is accurate.

Comment: AND job id 1 is over 5 years old, so should automatically be included regardless of reviews!

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Can you explain those 2 lines which contains dense rank function please?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow as the column name suggests its a windowed count of distinct locations within a given job.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow you can debug it by changing the select to `select * from cte` to understand how it works.